# What is the dimension of the subspace $S$ of the vector space of all $8×10$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $8 \times 8$ matrix and the rank of $A$ is $5$.

Let $M_{m \times n}(\Bbb{R})$ denotes the the vector space of all $m \times n$ matrices with real entries.

$$S=\{B\in M_{8 \times 10}(\Bbb{R}) \mid AB=0\}$$

> Question: What is the dimension of set $S$ ?

My try: As rank of $AB$ is $0$ and matrix $A$ only have to face the range of $B$ in product $AB$. So range space of $B$ must be contained in null space of $A$. So rank of $B \le 3$. I can't conclude forward from right here.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I tried :but i am not able to type mathematical expression !

Comment: There's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for people to learn formatting here. You can see how I've formatted your question by pressing [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4505433/edit) and looking at the code. You can also play around with the code, and see what happens in real time.

Comment: Please say what you have tried. So far the question is of type "no effort", and the guidelines recommend not to answer it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde edited!

Comment: @MeetPatel It will help to think of building $B$ column by column. You should convince yourself that each column of $B$ belongs to $\operatorname{Null} A$. That is, for every column $v$ of $B$, we have $Av = 0$. You have a free choice, from $\operatorname{Null} A$, for each of $B$'s $10$ columns. This might help count the dimensions.

Comment: Hint: Call that space $S(A)$ because it depends on the choice of the matrix $A$. Observe that if $L$ is any invertible $8\times 8$ matrix, then $S(LA)=S(A)$. This has the consequence that without loss of generality you can assume $A$ to be of reduced row echelon form. Furthermore, if $P$ is a permutation matrix (permuting columns here), we have $S(AP)=S(A)P^{-1}$. So you can assume that $A$ has a useful block structure with $I_5$ and zero blocks. Now you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** As you have correctly noted, $AB = 0$ if and only if the range of $B$ is a subset of the nullspace of $A$. Equivalently, $AB = 0$ if and only if *each column of $B$* is an element of the nullspace of $A$. With that in mind, start with a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ of the nullspace of $A$ and use this to construct a basis of $S$ such that each element of the basis has exactly one non-zero column.

How many elements are in this basis?

---

The basis I am hinting at is $\mathcal B = (M_1,M_2,M_3,\dots,M_k)$, where
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{v_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0},\\
M_2 = \pmatrix{v_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0},\\
M_3 = \pmatrix{v_3 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0},\\
M_4 = \pmatrix{0 & v_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0},\\
\vdots\\
M_k = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & v_3}.
$$

Comment: for each column to be in Null space of $A$ ,as $A$ is real matrix; there are not finite choice for single column

Comment: @Meet Of course not. However, perhaps you can find a basis of the subspace of $S$ consisting of all matrices for which that 1: all columns other than the single column are zero, and 2: the single possibly non-zero column is an element of the nullspace of $A$. I claim that this basis has $3$ elements.

Comment: @MeetPatel See my edit

Comment: correct ! Given ans is :30; and span of this set obviously give required set(i got it).how u got such ideas!  (thank you)

Answer (score 0):

Remember the dimension theorem
\begin{equation}
\dim(V)= \dim \mbox{rank}\ (T) + \dim \ker (T). 
\end{equation}
In this case $T$ is the transformation associated with matrix A and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(T)=5$.

Comment: can u specify $T$

Comment: $T(B)=AB$. Is clear that $T$ is a linear transformation

Comment: I believe: $T:\mathbb{R}^{8\times 10}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{8\times 10}:B\mapsto AB$.

Comment: So nullity is the required answer !

Comment: Yes, note that $\dim \ker(T)=\dim(V)-\dim \mbox{rank}\ (T)$. For clarity, $V=\mathbb{R}^{8\times 10}$ and $\mbox{rank} (T)=5$.

Answer (score 0):

$M_{m×n}(\mathbb{R}) $: Set of all $m×n$ matrices over $\Bbb{R}$.

$T:M_{8×8}(\Bbb{R})×M_{8×10}(\Bbb{R})\to M_{8×10}(\Bbb{R}) $ defined by $$T(A, B) =AB$$ is a Bilinear map.

For fixed $A\in M_{8×8}(\Bbb{R}) $ , $$T_A:M_{8×10}(\Bbb{R}) \to M_{8×10}(\Bbb{R}) $$ is a linear map.

Then $S=\ker(T_A) =\{B\in M_{8×10}(\Bbb{R}):T_A(B)=0\}$

Let $M=M(T_A) $ denote the matrix of $T_A$ with respect to standard basis $\mathcal{B}=\{E_{ij}:1\le i\le 8,1\le j\le 10\}$ where $E_{ij}$ has $1$ in $ij$-the place and zeros everywhere.

Then

$M=\begin{pmatrix}A& &&&\\&A&&&\\&&A&&\\&&&\ddots&&\\&&&&A\end{pmatrix}_{80×80}$

Matrix of $T_A$ is the block diagonal matrix with all diagonals $A$ and repeated $10$ times on the diagonal.

Hence $\operatorname{rank}(T_A) =10\times \operatorname{rank}(A) =10\times 5=50$

$\dim(\ker(T_A)) =80-50=30$

$$\text{or}$$

$\begin{align}\dim(\ker(T_A)) &=10\times \dim(\ker(A) \\&=10(8-\operatorname{rank}(A))\\&=10(8-5)\\&=30\end{align}$

Comment: i missed the simple way by creating associated matrix !

Answer (score 0):

We have that $AB=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{im}(B)\subset \ker(A)$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, $\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{dim}\ker(A)=8$, so $\operatorname{dim}\ker(A)=3$.

We can decompose such a $B$ as the composition
$$B:\mathbb R^{10}\stackrel{B'}{\longrightarrow} \ker(A)\stackrel{\iota}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb R^{8}$$

where $\iota$ is the inclusion of $\ker A$ into $\mathbb R^{8}$  Since the inclusion is injective, there is a unique $B'$ associated to each $B$ in our space.  So the collection of $B$ such that $AB=0$ is in one to one correspondence with $\hom(\mathbb R^{10},\ker(A)).$

Given two vector spaces, the dimension of the space of linear maps between them $\hom(V,W)=\operatorname{dim}(V)\cdot \operatorname{dim}(W)$.  So $\hom(\mathbb R^{10},\ker(A))=10\times 3=30.$